# TopSpeed ODBC Driver > SSIS > SQL Server 2019: Package cancels itself immediately after validation

Tags: sql-server, ssis, odbc

One of the smaller factories that my company owns uses an old ERP that's based on TPS database files and they require the TopSpeed ODBC driver for data transfer. I have successfully designed a staging table in my local (demo) data warehouse and assembled an ETL package in SSIS for one of the smallest tables they have that isn't completely empty. Not relevant, but the table contains RMA information. It only has two rows and six columns. The SSIS package runs quick and the data matches one for one between the .TPS source and SQL Server destination.

I am trying to replicate this process for any larger table, but the package seems to Cancel itself as soon as the validation phase is over, though the yellow wheel stays spinning on the ODBC Source tool forever. The table I'm trying now isn't that much bigger (182 rows, 10 columns).

Visual Studio isn't throwing any warnings or errors, so I don't know what to search for troubleshooting... I'll paste the entire Output below along with a picture of the workflow.

I have the Developer version of the TopSpeed driver. This causes a splash screen to pop anytime it's called, but I'm not aware of any limitations besides that.

```
SSIS package "C:\Users\placeholder.dtsx" starting.
Information: 0x4004300A at Update raw_CATEGORY, SSIS.Pipeline: Validation phase is beginning.
Information: 0x40043006 at Update raw_CATEGORY, SSIS.Pipeline: Prepare for Execute phase is beginning.
Information: 0x40043007 at Update raw_CATEGORY, SSIS.Pipeline: Pre-Execute phase is beginning.
Information: 0x4004300C at Update raw_CATEGORY, SSIS.Pipeline: Execute phase is beginning.
SSIS package "C:\Users\placeholder.dtsx" finished: Canceled.
```

[image: spinning forever]

Comment: _This causes a splash screen to pop anytime it's called, but I'm not aware of any limitations besides that._ That could be a problem in and of itself. SSIS packages tend to execute in a headless environment (without any Desktop interface or session), so the lack of a desktop could causes errors when the development driver tries to create and display the splash screen.

Comment: Maybe the driver has some code that disables itself for large tables. Why not try the "real" driver?

Comment: That's an interesting point, @AlwaysLearning. I'll see if I can get my boss to pay for a license. Thank you both.